# Show that a finite abelian group M admits a basis as a Z-module if and only if M = {0}

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, modules

Trying to show that : Show that a finite abelian group $M$ admits a basis as a $\Bbb Z$ -module if and only if $M =$ {$0$}.

The reverse direction being trivial, I am not sure what the forward direction means as I am new to the concept of a module. Any tips or clarifications much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is an $R$-module, a collection $(m_i)_{i \in I}$ of elements of $M$ forms a basis for $M$ (as a $R$-module) if and only if every element $m \in M$ can be represented **uniquely** as $m = \sum_{i \in I} r_i m_i$ for some $r_i \in R$ (where all but finitely many $r_i$ are required to vanish).

If $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module which admits a basis $(m_i)_{i \in I}$ then in particular if we choose some $i_0 \in I$ and look at the elements $(k \cdot m_{i_0})_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$, they must all be distinct and so $M$ must be infinite.

Comment: Ok thank you the uniqueness guarantees that there would be an infinite number that is very helpful.

Comment: @JamesDickens Yep. More generally, you can prove that if $M$ has a basis $(m_i)_{i \in I}$ then $M \approx \bigoplus_{i \in I} R$ (that is, $M$ is isomorphic to $|I|$ copies of $R$). In particular, if $R = \mathbb{Z}$ then $M$ must be infinite dimensional.